# Django admin - Raw Id Input on intermediate page

Tags: django, django-admin

I've have a Topic model in the django admin (v1.6).  I'm trying to make an action that takes the queryset and makes the objects aliases of another Topic.  This other Topic will be selected in an [intermediate page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages).  I am having a hard time understanding how to get the [Raw ID input](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) into the intermediate page, and I haven't seen any code like this.

Here are my models

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Alias(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='aliases')
```

My admin.py is something like this:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from breakingnews.topics.models import Topic, Alias

class TopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def make_alias(self, request, queryset):
        if request.POST.get('post'):
            # process the queryset here
            head = request.POST.get('head')
            tail = queryset

            for topic in tail:
                a, is_new = Alias.objects.get_or_create(name=topic.name, slug=topic.slug, topic=head)
        else:
            context = {
                'title': "To what topic would you like the alias to point?",
                'queryset': queryset,
                'action_checkbox_name': helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
            }
            return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/make_alias.html',
                context, current_app=self.admin_site.name)
    add_tag.short_description = "Make these topics an alias to another"

    ...

    actions = [
        add_tag,
    ]
admin.site.register(Topic, TopicAdmin)
```

And the make_alias.html is this:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n l10n admin_urls %}

{% block content %}
<p>{% blocktrans %}To what topic would you like the alias to point? {% endblocktrans %}</p>
<ul>{{ queryset|unordered_list }}</ul>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div>
    <input type="text" name="head" value="" />
    {% for obj in queryset %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ action_checkbox_name }}" value="{{ obj.pk|unlocalize }}" />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="make_alias" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="yes" />
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
    </div>
    <!-- <ul>{{ queryset|unordered_list }}</ul> -->

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you have an admin.py file?

Comment: Yes, I do. Sorry that my current work isn't accurately represented, I'll keep editing in useful information as I can.  I'm comfortable adding actions, but the big blocker for me is getting the raw_id_input style picker in the intermediate form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happened to make it work:

Add this to Admin.py:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from breakingnews.topics.models import Topic, Alias

class AliasCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    parents = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Topic.objects.all(),
        widget=ManyToManyRawIdWidget(
            Topic._meta.get_field('parents').rel, admin.site)
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ('parents',)

def make_alias(self, request, queryset):
    if request.POST.get('post'):
        # Handle the response
    else:
        formset = AliasCreateForm()
        context = {
            'title': "To what topic would you like the alias to point?",
            'queryset': queryset,
            'formset': formset,
            'action_checkbox_name': helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
            'action':'make_alias',
        }
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/make_alias.html',
                                context, current_app=self.admin_site.name)
make_alias.short_description = "Make these topics an alias to another"
```

And make_alias.html:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n l10n admin_urls %}

{% block extrahead %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <ul>{{ queryset|unordered_list }}</ul>
{{ formset }}

<br /><br />
{% for obj in queryset %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{ action_checkbox_name }}" value="{{ obj.pk|unlocalize }}" />
{% endfor %}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="{{action}}" />
<input type="hidden" name="post" value="yes" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```